# the use of 'THE' in relative clause

Tags: articles, definite-article, relative-clauses

which is correct or mostly used when the listener doesn't know which people I mean?
1

- *Do you know people I work with?*
- *Do you know ***the*** people I work with?*

2

- *I hate people who brag about how much money they have.*
- *I hate ***the*** people who brag about how much money they have.*

Comment: The relative clause has no effect on the meaning of "the". It is acting as a determiner with its usual meaning, (if you can answer the question "which people" then they are determined and that is marked with "the")

Comment: It's not about whether the *listener* knows which people are meant, it's whether the *speaker* does

Comment: If you hate people you work with, I guess you can't work anywhere.

Comment: @AndyBonner can you explain me what you mean?

Comment: I mean the same as James' comment, really: the choice of whether to use "the" or not has to do with your meaning, not who the listener knows. You would say "the people" if you're talking about a specific set of people, and just "people" if you don't have any specific ones in mind.

Comment: Which means that both versions are correct and are often used, so this question can't be answered as it is. Please use the "edit" button to tell a bit more about what kind of meaning you'd like to create.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct, but the meaning changes a very small amount. In almost all cases, native speakers will know what you mean regardless of which version you use.

### **The People**

Adding the definite article *the* indicates a specific, finite group of people. Saying "Do you know the people I work with?" asks if the listener knows (broadly) all of the people OR if they know the group as a whole. Saying "I hate the people who brag about how much money they have," implies that the speaker knows either specific individuals who do this OR that they think of this as a category/group of people, different from other groups.

### People

Omitting the article leaves the meaning less specific or more flexible. Saying "Do you know people I work with?" asks if the listener knows anyone that the speaker works with. The listener could answer yes if they know one person, two people, or more. They don't need to know the whole group.

Saying "I hate people who brag about how much money they have," means that the speaker is talking abstractly about some people, but it isn't clear who or how many or even if they have specific people in mind. They also don't need to think of this as a group-defining trait.