# Usage of Articles in Relative clauses

Tags: articles, definite-article, relative-clauses, indefinite-article

*1. Tom is talking to **a** woman. Do you know her?

2. Do you know **the** woman Tom is talking to?

3. **The** man I was sitting next to on the plane talked all the time.*

In the first sentence, we used '**a woman**', assuming the listener didn't know about her.
However, in the second sentence, we used '**the woman**' even when the listener didn't know about which woman I meant.
And we did the same thing for the third sentence.

I know that article usage doesn't depend on relative clauses, but seeing 1 and 2 makes me think about why we chose '***The***' instead of '***a***' because in both cases the listener didn't about the woman at all (take both sentences as different), yet we assumed that we should use **the**.

- How and when to use articles in relative clauses?
- Does it depend on if the listener is aware of what/who is being talked about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the use of 'THE' in relative clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/347110/the-use-of-the-in-relative-clause)

Comment: The other answer mentions 'The relative clause has no effect on the meaning of "the"',  mostly true, however in sentence #2 here "the" would likely switch to "that" if the clause were removed "do you know that woman?".  "The" implies she is determined, but the determination depends a bit on the clause itself.

Comment: @Sam does the determination depend on the clause?

Comment: Does the determination depend on the clause? Well, lets say you're discussing a completely unknown person (in every possible way that can be imagined) then maybe you wouldn't use "the", since "the" means "the one you know about, somehow".   But a clause can give you this information.  "The one... who you are talking to".  Thus, the clause adds the determining information.   After it has added the determining information, you are justified in using the article "the".

Comment: @Sam then sentences like "Do you know people I work with?" I've provided the relative clause which adds the determining information, but still, we are not using 'the' before 'people'.
I think that's because the relative clause doesn't depend on the article or vice-versa.

Comment: "people" is plural, and there are multiple choices there.  In your sentence #2, with one woman, the definite article is required.  Thus, some amount of 'dependence'.